# Error invalid_grant - expired authorization code while running sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, jwt, authorization, ci

I run the command from my build job within Teamcity CI:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid '%SFDX_HUB_CONSUMER_KEY%' --jwtkeyfile config/server.key --username %SFDX_HUB_USERNAME% --setalias hub1 --loglevel trace
```

But i get the error:

```
ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - expired authorization code 
username: abc@wyz.com, 
clientId: xxxxxxx, 
loginUrl: https://login.salesforce.com, 
privateKey: config/server.key 

Try this: 
Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access].
Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.
```

I already verified the consumer key from the connected app and i also checked the key, which looks ok. Because this all works from my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end the problem was in the server time being way off. So if you have this problem, check your CI/CD server time. If it's off, please sync the time using NTP sync:

```
sudo service ntp restart
```